# The use of get_template_part() returns 'invalid argument' loading options

Tags: get-template-part

I would like to avoid the `include_once()` in order to remove one INFO using Theme Check, and when I try to load my Options page using `get_template_part('custom-options');` it returns the message:

> «Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in [...]/custom-options.php
>   on line 83».

Where the code is the typical:

```
//[...]
<?php foreach ($options as $value) { //#83
  switch ($value['type']) { case "open": ?>
<?php break; case "close": ?>
<?php break; case "title": ?>
    <h3><?php echo $value['name']; ?></h3>
//[...]
```

I'm not sure, but perhaps it's not allowed for loading options.

Then I tried `load_template( trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . 'custom-options.php' );` with the same result.

**My questions are:**
Is that possible to load the options file by using `get_template_part()`?

If not, is there a way to load the options file and, at the same time, being it valid with the Theme Check plugin?

Comment: where do you set `$options` and is it in the scope of the file you are currently trying to use it in?

Comment: That's not a Theme Check **error**; it's merely **INFO**. The `get_template_part()` function is a *template tag*, and is intended to include *template-part* files, within the *template*. It is **not** intended to include *functional* files within `functions.php`. You should use `include()` or `require()` to include *functional* files in `functions.php`.

Comment: @Milo, I have the options defined in the file custom-options.php, and then I retrieve some of them in the functions.php file (and also in the other files, of course). I also separated the array of the Settings in a third file, like this: functions.php loads custom-options.php, and this one loads custom-options-array.php. Always approximately at the top of the files.

Comment: @ChipBennett, yes, you are right, that's INFO instead of an error. I'm sorry for this mistake. I'm gonna fix it in the post. Thanks for the explanation also :)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a read here. Kaiser wrote a complete article on this on his blog

I quote from that

> Although get_template_part is similar to a PHP include or require, you
>   should not use it to include things like your theme options code,
>   sidebars registration, custom widgets, etc. The get_template_part
>   function should only be used to get template parts.

You can go and check out the complete article [here](http://kovshenin.com/2013/get_template_part/)

Answer (score 1):

You are having scope issues. When file is included inside of a function — it has a scope of that function.

That's why [`load_template()`](http://queryposts.com/function/load_template/) (which all template "including" function in WP trickle down to) declares number of WP's globals so that they can be accessed inside the templates.

So you'll have either to pass data through globals or otherwise, rework your code from using separate template file, or use some other approach (like dedicated non-PHP template files for example).

Comment: I'm not sure if the retrievement method is a problem in that case, because the options page works perfect when I load the options using `include_once()`. But yes, I think that you are right about it, the loading method generates scope issues on it, and as others say, I have to use `include_once()` instead of `get_template_part()`, so I will skip the info message of Theme Check plugin. Thanks again for your answer! :)

Comment: @Gerard `include_once` is _not a function_, it's a language control structure.